# tag objects with different tags having same value using django-taggit

Tags: django, django-taggit

I am learning to use django-taggit from a couple of days.

using taggit we can tag a tag an object with any tag.

I am currently working on a project which includes tagging of media files.

My problem is I am not able to figure out how can i tag a file on basis of different tags having same values.

I mean for example,if i want to search for all movies where Mel Gibson was director as well as actor how can i tag iron man movie object based on Director as well as Actor?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You have actually two tags named the same way but with different meaning. Tags carry meaning, so you could inherit TagBase and add a "category" field to your custom tag, this way, you will have:

Mel Gibson -> director
Mel Gibson -> actor

So, you create your own tag class, and specify a tag field in your Movie model, passing a custom Through variable. Read the doc of django-taggit for doing this. Hope this helps.